# Is it possible to create segments for Custom audiences via Facebook Marketing API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I has been created some custom audiences via Facebook API. 
(by this docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences-api/mobile-apps)
Is it possible to create segments for audiences via API ? I find this possibility on Ads Manager interface, but can't find in API's docs.

Comment: what do you mean by segments?

Comment: Segments, created by Facebook analytics (https://www.facebook.com/analytics/<app_id> => segments button on top page)